# MySQL Query to move/copy certain rows rather than the entire table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently using the following to move/copy the entire table from one table to another, which works perfectly.

**`INSERT INTO archivedpks SELECT * FROM pks`**

However I want to be able to specify what rows I want to move from the **`pks`** table to the **`archivedpks`** table.

My table has an **`id`** column, I want to **only** move the rows with an **`id`** from **`25`** to **`250`**

How would I modify the query to only work on those rows?

Comment: `INSERT INTO archivedpks SELECT * FROM pks WHERE id BETWEEN 25 AND 250`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO archivedpks SELECT * FROM pks WHERE id>=25 and id<=250
```

Comment: what's the benefits of using your method against Sean's method (`between` x `and` y)

Comment: Both works same without any hiccups. It just a alternative way of doing this